# Error while iterating a dataframe using Java Spark foreach function

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, foreach, dataset

**edited**

I am trying to iterate trough a dataframe to create another one. In this example I am not using data from the first one, it is just to show what I am trying to do. However, the idea is to use the first one to generate a new one much bigger based on data from the first one.

Whatever I try in the void function, I always get the error in the `foreach`.

Sample dataframe to iterate:

```
Dataset<Row> obtencionRents = spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
        new testRentabilidades("0000A0","PORTAL","4-ANUAL","asdasd","asdasd"),
        new testRentabilidades("00A00","PORTAL","","asdasd","sdasd"),
        new testRentabilidades("00A","PORTAL","4-ANUAL","asdasd","asdasd")
), testRentabilidades.class);
```

Foreach function to iterate sample dataframe:

```
obtencionRents.toJavaRDD().foreach(new VoidFunction<Row>() {
        public void call(Row r) throws Exception {

           //add registers to new collection/arraylist/etc.
        }
    });
```

The Error I've got:

```
Driver stacktrace:
2021-11-03 17:34:41 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 0 failed: foreach at CargarRentabilidades.java:154, took 0,812094 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:419)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:157)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.transformacionRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.coleccionRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:78)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades.coleccionCargaRentabilidades(CargarRentabilidades.java:52)
    at batchload.proceso.MainBatch.init(MainBatch.java:59)
    at batchload.BatchloadRentabilidades.main(BatchloadRentabilidades.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:419)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:157)
    at batchload.proceso.builder.CargarRentabilidades$1.call(CargarRentabilidades.java:154)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:921)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Versions:

mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0
Java 1.8
IntelliJ 2021 1.2 Community
Spark library versions 2.11

other dependency versions I am using:

hadoop 2.7, spark 2.3.0, java driver 2.7, spark catalyst,core,hive,sql ....all 2.11:2.3.0, scala scala-library:2.11.12

Stuck with this, any help is more than welcome

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to serialization issue.
Can you try converting your anonymous Function into static method of class?

Comment: Thanks of the answer, I'll try it

Comment: Cannot make it static because I use a spark session in the function and in the class and throws exception because is not serializable, I'll have to try some other way.  Get that data from the first dataframe convert it to something I can read row by row then use these values to construct a new bigger dataframe.  Everything I tried with the 'foreachrow' functions throws that weird exception.

Comment: didn't manage to make it work. finally I converted the dataframe into a list then use a for loop to get all rows of the list:   List<Row> newList = df.collectAsList();